# Word symbols font dictionary?

Tags: applications

Is there a dictionary I can download that has the symbols used in Microsoft Word for Mac? For example the Paragraph formatting mark that looks like a backwards P, or the icons used in the ribbon? I would use a combination on the keyboard to get the image.

Comment: You mean like typing a pilcrow? ¶ which other symbols?

Comment: The keyboard combo for ¶ is option 7 on the US layout.  If your purpose is to type these symbols into some text you are writing, you are looking for a font, not a dictionary.